# How to set default value for all dags with DAG cluster policy?

Tags: airflow

I am trying to set two default values for all my dags. For that, I have created the file `airflow_local_settings.py` in my home directory of Airflow with the following code (trying to follow the example in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#dag-level-cluster-policy):

```
def dag_policy(dag: DAG):
    dag.catchup = False
    dag.default_args['email'] = 'blabla'
```

However, I get the error:

```
Error: name 'DAG' is not defined
```

If I leave the code as:

```
def dag_policy(dag: DAG):
        dag.catchup = False
        dag.default_args['email'] = 'blabla'
```

Then the dags run with catchup=True and no email. How could I solve it? Thanks

Comment: Cluster Policy isn't really acting as default values. The attributes that you define in Policy will will have precedence over what you define in the dag. Also what airflow version are you running?

Comment: I am with Airflow 1.10.14. Maybe this is only for 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAG Policy was added in [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/12184) and available only in Airflow >= 2.0 since you are running 1.10.14 this feature is not available for you.